# Help me remember the name of an old animated sci-fi (apocalyptic) movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

When I was young I remember my mother bringing me a movie home from goodwill. The movie was in the 80s style if I remember correctly. I don't remember much about the movie other than a masked character who always wore a red suit, carried a rifle and rode an ostrich like creature. I think this character never spoke and died at some point in the movie. The front cover of the movie has this red cloaked character mounted on his ostrich like creature with his gun.

If I remember right, the movie's landscape was very bleak and apocalyptic and was inhabited with characters wearing the same cloak and riding the same beast as the character mentioned above only with a different color scheme.

Any help would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

This sounds like [Wizards](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076929/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

> On a post-apocalyptic Earth, a wizard and his faire folk comrades fight an evil wizard who's using technology in his bid for conquest.

[image]

It has some pretty funny moments.

*Sidenote:* This was the first cartoon I ever saw which had profanity in it. At the time I thought it was illegal for cartoons to use profanity, and wondered how they got away with it.

Comment: @John If this is the correct answer, please mark it as 'accepted'.

Comment: Hmm I had mercifully deleted this from my memory banks (saw it in the theater when it came out).  May have to look it up.